# How to read a cookie from javascript and display it in next page(Result.jsp) when body onload

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="JavaScript/CommonJS.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="pink">    
    <div align="center" >
        <h1> <font color="red" >JavaScript task</font></h1>
    </div>

    <div  align="left" style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:13px">
        Number of Characters Left:
        <label id="lblcount" style="background-color:#E2EEF1;
                   color:Red;font-weight:bold;">100</label><br/>
        <textarea style="overflow:auto;resize:none" id="mytextbox" 
              rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="100" wrap="hard"
          onkeyup="LimtCharacters(this,100,'lblcount');"></textarea>
    </div>           

    <p align="center">
        <input type="button" id="view" name="view" 
               value="Next" onclick="SaveData()">               
    </p>         
</body>
```

This is my index.jsp page when i click on next button it is going to `CommonJS.js`(javascript) there i'm saving the data in cookie and forwarding to Result.jsp,in Result.jsp page how can i read cookie and display it in my `resul.jsp` page

Javascript is:

```
function LimtCharacters(txtMsg, CharLength, indicator) {
var chars = txtMsg.value.length;
document.getElementById(indicator).innerHTML = CharLength - chars;
if (chars > CharLength) {
    txtMsg.value = txtMsg.value.substring(0, CharLength);
}
}

function createCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
if (exdays) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
}
else expires = "";
document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+expires+";path=/";   
}

function readCookie(name) {
var nameEQ = name + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0)
        return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
}
return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Anybody guide me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the body onload="functioncall()" directive to call a function on load. To display it, a simple method would be to have a div in your page that will be filled with the cookie value from JavaScript.

The code would look like this:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function displayCookie() {
      document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = readCookie('myCookie');
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="displayCookie()">    
  <div id="myDiv" ></div>
</body>
```